# How to open multiple jquery ui draggables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Im a Beginner in jquery and got some Problem with the draggable widget.
It seems that the selector cant get the next draggable class when the "button" is clicked.
The thing is that i cannot use IDs for the selector because the table is filled dynamic and the number of rows varies.
Is there a way i can solve this only changing the javascript?
Thank you all for your effort!

CodePen here: https://codepen.io/Zerberuus/pen/aWENje

HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>  <THEAD>
      <TR>
        <TH>col1</TH>
        <TH>col2</TH>
        <TH>col3</TH>
        <TH>col4</TH>
        <TH>col5</TH>
     </TR></THEAD>
      <TBODY><TBODY><TR>
      <TD>random</TD>
     <TD>random2</TD>
     <TD class="press" style="color:blue;">clickhere</TD>
    
        <div class="draggable">
          <p>Drag me around</p>
          <p>Box 1</p>
         </div>
    
     <TD class="press" style="color:red;">clickhere2</TD>
    
        <div class="draggable">
          <p>Drag me around</p>
          <p>Box 2</p>
         </div>
      
     <TD>random3</TD>
    </TR></TBODY></table> 
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$( ".draggable" ).draggable(); //init draggable

$(".draggable").hide(); //hide at first

$(".press").click(function () { // fadeIn the next .draggable class
        $(this).next(".draggable:first").fadeIn("slow");
});

}); //end of script
```

CSS:

```
.draggable{
  position:relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0.5em;
  line-height: 0px;
  border-radius:25px;
  border:1px solid #000000;;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #c1c1c1; 
}
```

Comment: @Nemus Please don't add a snippet just to "format" the HTML. If you don't also include the JavaScript and CSS needed to run properly, the snippet is useless. Snippets are meant to be runnable, self-contained ways to demonstrate code behavior.

Comment: can someone help me with my problem or has an alternative to draggables?

Comment: You have `div` tags mixed in between `td`s. Since that's illegal (a `div` can't be a child of `tr`), the `div`s are moved outside of the `table`. There's no `.next('.draggable')` since all of the draggables have moved away. You could make the `.draggable` objects into `td`s, but you'll need to deal with positioning.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Indeed it works with table element like td etc. but as you guessed i now got problems with the positioning.
Is there a way to get the unhided element independent from the surrounding td`s?

Comment: I'd consider `position: absolute` if you *really* can't leave a `data-...` attribute on the button pointing to the `id` of the element to be dragged. If you *can* do that, then you can move the `div`s outside of the `table` where they belong, and find them via jQuery's `.data()`

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned by [Paul Roub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1324/paul-roub), there is HTML Syntax issues. These should be addressed first.

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <TH>col2</TH>
      <TH>col3</TH>
      <TH>col4</TH>
      <TH>col5</TH>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <TR>
      <TD>random</TD>
      <TD>random2</TD>
      <TD class="press" style="color:blue;" data-target="0">clickhere</TD>
      <TD class="press" style="color:red;" data-target="1">clickhere2</TD>
      <TD>random3</TD>
    </TR>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="draggable">
  <div class="textdiv">
    <span id="titletext">Title Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="titlediv">
    <div class="icondiv fa-users" title="user">
    </div>
    <div class="icondiv fa-list" title="entries">
    </div>
    <div class="icondiv fa-cogs" title="OSCM config">
    </div>
    <div class="icondiv fa-sign-out" title="promotable workspace">
    </div>
    <div class="icondiv fa-database" title="ODT">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="draggable">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
  <p>Box 2</p>
</div>
```

You had `div` elements as children of the `tr`. I moved them out of the table. You also had two `tbody` elements and only one closing and only one needed. I removed the unnecessary element.

No big changes to CSS. Just one:

**CSS**

```
.draggable {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0.5em;
  line-height: 0px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
}
```

You can then take advantage of jQuery and jQuery UI to chain and improve your code.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable().hide(); //init draggable
  $(".press").click(function(e) { // fadeIn the next .draggable class
    console.log("Click Event, Target: ", $(e.target));
    var target = $(".draggable").eq($(this).data("target"));
    target.position({
      my: "center top",
      at: "center bottom+2",
      of: this
    }).fadeIn("slow");
  });
  $(".icondiv").click(
    function() {
      $(this).next(".iconpop:first").show();
    });
});
```

Since there is no good method to selecting a specific `.draggable`, you will likely have to adjust the HTML in some way to help yourself. You could also make use of `.index()` with a little work.

Since each `td` is a child of `tr`, `.index()` will tell you the index of that element in the row and you can use that to select a specific element using `.eq()`. If column 3 and 4 are always going to be the clickable elements, you could work from this. Consider the following:

**HTML**

```
<TR>
  <TD>random 1</TD>
  <TD>random 2</TD>
  <TD class="press" style="color:blue;">click here 1</TD>
  <TD class="press" style="color:red;">click here 2</TD>
  <TD>random 3</TD>
</TR>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".press").click(function(e) {
  $(".draggable").eq($(this).index() - 2).position({
    my: "center top",
    at: "center bottom+2",
    of: this
  }).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

In this, `$(this).index()` will return either `2` or `3`, and when we subtract `2`, we can now call index `0` or `1` respectively.

Now it's not clear if you will have 1 `div` that all the rows use, or a unique `div` for every row.

I hope this helps.